# How to build a java Main Menu

Tags: java, swing, menu, program-entry-point, cardlayout

Obviously I am trying to make a main menu using the swing components. I understand that in order to make my menu happen, I have to utilize `CardLayout`, which I do in the code below:

(Everything is imported of course)

```
 public class Screen extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

int width, height;

JButton play = new JButton("play");
JButton settings = new JButton("settings");
JButton exit = new JButton("exit");
JButton mainMenu = new JButton("main menu");

CardLayout layout = new CardLayout();

JPanel panel = new JPanel();
JPanel game = new JPanel();
JPanel menu = new JPanel(); 

public Screen(int width, int height) {
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;

    panel.setLayout(layout);        
    addButtons();

    setSize(width, height);
    setResizable(false);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    setVisible(true);
    setTitle("BUILD YOUR EMPIRE");
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    requestFocus();

}

private void addButtons() {

    play.addActionListener(this);
    settings.addActionListener(this);
    exit.addActionListener(this);
    mainMenu.addActionListener(this);

    //menu buttons
    menu.add(play);
    menu.add(settings);
    menu.add(exit);

    //game buttons
    game.add(mainMenu);

    //background colors
    game.setBackground(Color.MAGENTA);
    menu.setBackground(Color.GREEN);

    //adding children to parent Panel
    panel.add(menu,"Menu");
    panel.add(game,"Game");

    add(panel);
    layout.show(panel,"Menu");

}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {

    Object source = event.getSource();

    if (source == exit) {
        System.exit(0);
    } else if (source == play) {
        layout.show(panel, "Game");
    } else if (source == settings){

    } else if (source == mainMenu){
        layout.show(panel, "Menu");
    }

    }
}
```

But when I run it, only the exit button works.
When I hit the settings button nothing happens (as expected)
but when I hit play button it crashes and gives me this error:

```
 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: wrong parent for CardLayout
at java.awt.CardLayout.checkLayout(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.CardLayout.show(Unknown Source)
at Screen.Buttons(Screen.java:69)
at Screen.<init>(Screen.java:31)
at Window.main(Window.java:29)
```

I dont understand what I am doing wrong.
Any help on this will be greately appreciated thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found it!

It was a matter of wrong order:

```
Buttons();
panel.setLayout(layout);        
layout.addLayoutComponent(panel, "Menu");
```

is wrong because you obviously need to set up the CardLayout in the `panel` before doing anything (like `show`) with it. So:

```
panel.setLayout(layout);        
layout.addLayoutComponent(panel, "Menu");
Buttons();
```

Although I don't know why do you need the line:

```
layout.addLayoutComponent(panel, "Menu");
```

looking at the [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) it does not mention the necessity to use it.

Also method names should start in lower case, I was confused for a moment thinking that `Buttons` was a class. And you should use more descriptive names:

`addButtons()` instead of `Buttons()`

`gamePanel` instead of `game`

and so on.

Good job providing (not very extensive) relevant code, next time you should try adding a `main` also so we can just execute and test it :)

Comment: Oh..wow.. spent 1 whole day on this ?! 0.o.. Ah well.. Appreciate you took the time and helped me out, I'll be sure to put your advice to use thanks a lot :)

Comment: Don't add components directly to the layout manager, but instead, you should be adding them to the container directly, this ensures that they will actually be made available to the screen

Comment: Uhm.. could you please explain how is what i wrote down any different from what you are saying? I put all the Jpanels and their comps to an extra Jpanel (le container) and then added the last one to the layout. no?

Answer (score 0):

Try swapping these lines...

```
panel.setLayout(layout);
addButtons();
```

Basically, when you try and `show` the first screen, the `CardLayout` is not associated with your `panel`, which is, obviously, a invalid parent